# Foxpro where expression invalid?

Tags: sql, where-clause, foxpro, visual-foxpro

```
lcVillkor1 = "table.numbers > 1"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE lcVillkor1 ORDER BY table.numbers
```

I got the error -  `SQL: WHERE clause is invalid`.

I've tried almost every possible combination

`"table.numbers > 1", (table.numbers > 1), "(table.numbers > '1')"` etc..

Im trying to get some posts (where a number is greater then 1) from a table to print out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `&` before the variable to expand it:

```
lcVillkor1 = "table.numbers > 1"

SELECT * FROM table WHERE &lcVillkor1 ORDER BY table.numbers
```

Comment: @jerry: the (variable) syntax is for 'name expressions', which are similar to, but not the same as, macro substitution - you can use them only when FoxPro is looking for a name.  So if the tablename were stored in a variable, you could say "SELECT * FROM (tablename) ..."

Comment: How about EVAL(lcVillkor1) ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't just put a variable name in a line of code and have it execute.  Instead, build up your SQL command as a text variable, and then use something like macro substitution to execute it:

```
lcVillkor1 = "table.numbers > 1" 
lcSql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " + lcVillkor1 + " ORDER BY table.numbers"
&lcSql
```

Also, for future reference, perhaps table and field names close to reserved words - eg "table" and "numbers" - may not be ideal.

Comment: Thanks, I'll see if that helps!
And the names are not the real names. Just to make it easier here.

Comment: Did not work. Im trying to get some posts (where a number is greater then 1) from a table to print out.

Comment: When you say "Did not work", what exactly happened?  Did you get an error message? Did it run, but return the wrong results?

Answer (score 0):

Macro substitution works fine (in both the examples given previously). If you use VFP9 you can also use the function EXECSCRIPT() after you've built the query string:

```
lcVillkor1 = "table.numbers > 1" 
lcSql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE " + lcVillkor1 + " ORDER BY table.numbers"
EXECSCRIPT(lcsql)
```